# Inspect RSS memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, memory-leaks, nuxt.js

**Background**

Im investigating a potential memory leak in a nuxt project.
We can only see the issue in production via the metrics of the AWS ECS that serves it.

I've been building the project locally with the --inspect flag and using siege to stress it, but the heap snapshots tell me nothing, and even though I can see a spike in memory usage, its always fully GC'ed after a "siege".

**Current issues**

If i run process.memoryUsage(), in the "node console" I can finally see that RSS is not GC'ed after a siege, it keeps increasing. So heap is stable, RSS is not. I've read that RSS is not included in heap snapshots and that it might not be any leak, just a need for more memory.

**Question**

Is there any way to inspect the RSS memory and see whats in there?
How can I figure out if there is a leak or a general need for more memory?

Nuxt version 2.15.4

Node version 12.22.6